# Unable to locate gdb frame for python bytecode interpreter

Tags: python, linux, gdb, pyenv

I ty to get a stacktrace from the running python process, using gdb. The python is running in an virtualenv managed by pyenv, on Ubuntu 16.4.

I tried this:
`sudo gdb ~/.pyenv/versions/bla/bin/python -p <PID>`

Then I do not have the extensions available, so I do

`symbol-file /usr/bin/python3.5-dbg`

Then when I run py-list, I get the following error:

Unable to locate gdb frame for python bytecode interpreter.

Also tried:
`sudo gdb /usr/bin/python3.5-dbg -p <PID>` and same error.

Any other way? Or an easier approach?

Comment: Was the python process compiled with debugging flags?

Comment: No, a python script ran with python. The python itself, I installed using pyenv.

Comment: If you run gdb without the sudo, do things work? You'll probably have to do `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` to temporarily allow gdb to access processes that it didn't create.  (Get approval from your responsible security people, if necessary, since this makes your system slightly less secure).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick  Thanks for the response. Is there no other way? also for `py-bt` I get "Unable to locate python frame".

Comment: There may be other workarounds, but the straightforward way to solve your problem is to get a working environment and then see how it differs from the non-working environment. Alternatively, can you can give us enough details about your setup that we can reproduce the problem on our own Ubuntu systems?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I got it to work by reinstalling python using (python -k) and then sourced libpython.py in my .gdbinit. What I am confused about, is that, I did not need to have the python3.5-dbg package.

Comment: a convenience command: echo 'add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python3.4-dbg-gdb.py' >> ~/.gdbinit  - insert your appropriate name of the python dbg file

Answer (score 2):

Probably your python version in the virtual env is incompatible with the python dbg package, which is compatible with the python at /usr/bin/. I've solved this problem by copying the python at /usr/bin to the virtual env and re-running. Even if both pythons are the same version the build date seems to make a big difference for gdb debugging.